# Vertically align span:after relative to text

Tags: html, sass

I made a menu with links that have "list bullets", reacting to hover, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7anJ.jpg).

Each item is wrapped by a **span**, and use **:after** to create the bullets.

The bullets are vertically aligned to the bottom of the text, and I want them to be centered.

However, trying to center it by using `vertical-align: middle;` (and any other means I could manage to find) results in this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V62B.png) (inspecting it shows the text is properly centered on the container) and I can't seem to find any way to get it properly centered.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tan90/n1yLaj70/28/) is the fiddle.

Comment: Can you make a code sample?

Comment: Should have added it from the start, sorry about that. Just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try if this code does what you need:

```
%linkBase {  
  $fontSize: 40px;
  line-height:40px;
  font-size: $fontSize;
  position:relative;
  &::after {
    $bulletHeight: $fontSize * 0.8;

    content: '';

    display: inline-block;

    width: 2px;
    height: 40px;

    background-color: black;
    top:50%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-20px;
  }
}

.link {
  @extend %linkBase;
}

.linkCentered {
  @extend %linkBase;
}
```

The idea is that you set the original link to be relative, then set the "after"element to be absolutely positioned. Then you set the "top" of that element to 50%, which pushes it half way down, then you pull it back up with a margin-top of half its height.
This is a common method of centering items.